# How to apply a patch

Tags: java, matlab, windows-xp, patch

I have this patch code which i downloaded from a web article (Calling Matlab from Java).
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html

But I donot know how to apply it in my windowsXp running computer. 
What I'm trying to do is call Matlab script file from java. I have found the necessary source codes and every thing but this mater is holding be back.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's the patch code.

```
Index: MatlabControl.java
===================================================================
RCS file: /cvsroot/tinyos/tinyos-1.x/tools/java/net/tinyos/matlab/MatlabControl.java,v
retrieving revision 1.3
diff -u -r1.3 MatlabControl.java
--- MatlabControl.java 31 Mar 2004 18:43:50 -0000 1.3
+++ MatlabControl.java 16 Aug 2004 20:36:51 -0000
@@ -214,7 +214,8 @@
          matlab.evalConsoleOutput(command);
          }else{
-               matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args, 0, null);
+               //     matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args, 0, null);
+               matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.toString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply that patch to the file [MatlabControl.java](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/MatlabControl.java). On Unix, you have the standard `patch` program to do that, but that ofcourse isn't normally present on Windows.

But looking at the patch file, it's very small and you could easily do the change by hand. Look at the patch file: The lines with a `-` in the left column must be removed. The lines with a `+` must be added.

So you must look in `MatlabControl.java` and remove this line:

```
matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args, 0, null);
```

And add these lines:

```
//     matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args, 0, null);
matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args);
```

In other words, it's a very small and simple change, you just have to remove the last two arguments to the method call to  `fevalConsoleOutput()`.

If you want the `patch` command (and lots of other Unix utilities) on Windows, you could download and install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 6):

I'd download the standard UNIX [`patch`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm) tool and use:

```
patch -p0 <my_patch.diff
```

Comment: You may want to explain the OP that `patch` should be run in the directory containing `MatlabControl.java`.

Comment: So what I have to do is copy the code in to a file named 'my_patch.diff' and save it in the folder that MatlabControl.java file is and run above command in console, right?

Comment: Yes, `cd C:\directory\which\contains\MatlabControl.java` and then `patch -p0 < my_patch.diff`. Make sure that `patch` is in your `$PATH` or specify its absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

If you use dev tools like Eclipse you can easily apply it as it is an option in the contextual menu (right click) go to Team - > Apply Patch. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

This patch is so small, you can easily apply it by hand.

So simply open the file `MatlabControl.java` and change line 214 (the one prepended with `-`) to fit the lines prepended with `+`.

After that your code should look like:

```
    else{
//                    matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args, 0, null);
        matlab.fevalConsoleOutput(command, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JMI (Java-to-Matlab Interface)'s Matlab class and its fevalConsoleOutput method are explained here: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/

Answer (score 0):

By Tortoise  SVN, we can apply patch by following the below way. Click on Apply patch and browse the patch file.

[Tortoise SVN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLucY.png)

[image]