# How to use x.diff.txt patch a project?

Tags: git, patch

I opened an issue on tmux https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1225

The maintainer told me

> try something like this x.diff.txt then show tmux logs from -vvvv

x.diff.txt is :https://github.com/tmux/tmux/files/1609045/x.diff.txt

It looks like git diff. I think it is a kind of patches, but how do I apply this file to the whole project? I only used tortoisegit to resolve conflict.

Comment: have you tried `git apply` ?

Comment: and you tagged `C` because?

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya tmux is c, I think it may be related to c make tool .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581644/how-to-apply-a-patch)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of "How to apply a patch" but it was still useful to me, because literally the exact  same thing happened to me (the tmux maintainer gave me x.diff.txt on my gh issue).

I knew it was a patch but it wasn't evident from the extension nor the frontmatter of the file how I was supposed to use it, or what to search for, so I googled "how to apply x.diff" and wound up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned `git apply` From https://www.devroom.io/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

For my problem

```
git clone https://github.com/tmux/tmux

cp x.diff.txt tmux & cd tmux

# take a look at what changes are in the patch
git apply --stat x.diff.txt

# test the patch before you actually apply it, no output means fine
git apply --check x.diff.txt

# If you don't own the project 
git apply x.diff.txt 

# If you own the project 
git am x.diff.txt
```